# Should favorite tag highlighting in question lists be changed?

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

Currently, when a question is tagged with one of your favorite tags, it gets a background color to better get your attention:

[image: background color highlighting]

On some sites, this can be somewhat overwhelming.  I'm proposing limiting this highlighting to tags only; for example, a border on the favorite tag:

[image: tag border highlighting]

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm biased, but I like it a lot. Easier on the eyes too!

Comment: I kinda like the way it does it now to be honest. It's far easier for me to see the questions I'm interested in at a glance (well, it is if you haven't got every tag under the sun favourited!) with the current highlighting.

Comment: What about changing the background of the featured tag as well? A little darker or something?

Comment: @Haney That would be a happy medium I think, keeping the higher visibility. Perhaps change the hyperlink colour as well (or is that a little too much?)

Comment: I don't like this because it takes your sight away from the question title and onto the tag(s) themself. I like it the way it is.

Comment: Why not just make the color lighter so it's not so overwhelming?

Comment: @animuson yes, that's a possibility, too.  I should most likely have asked this on meta.so (and I probably will do that later), as our [homepage redesign](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269769/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-2) puts *a lot* of highlighting on one's SO homepage.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I posted a similar question here, a bit different styling than yours, if you're interested, check it out: [Favorite Tag Highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278354/favorite-tag-highlighting)

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ looks good - i'll make sure our designers see it.