# Favorite Tag Highlighting

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

There are numerous posts within the network about changing the highlighting color of questions that contain a favorited tag.

- [Should favorite tag highlighting in question lists be changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238591/307724)
- [Color for “Favorite Tags” questions on new SO design needs to be stronger](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283674/1454538)
- [Darker color for favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283871/1454538)

None of the questions listed above have been answered or given any sort of status (declined, pending, ect..), so I am posting this here with a slightly different request.

As others have mentioned, I find the current highlighting a bit difficult to read on sites that use the yellowish background, it really messes with my eyes.

I would like to suggest removing the background color adding a visual indicator to the side of the question summary.

I came up with the following, I've added a border to the left side of the question summary with the main color of each sites theme; Stack Overflow orange, and Super User blue.

Interesting questions are still clearly visible in the list and the content is easy to read.

[image: Stack Overflow favorite tag highlighting]

[image: Super User favorite tag highlighting]

Comment: The current yellowish background is ugly and makes my eyes bleed / me not want to have any favourite tags when I can't use SOX (i.e, mobile)

Comment: 11 hours until I can start a bounty, but I wanna start one *now* :c

Comment: @cat that would be pointless, SE team is [already looking into it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238591/should-favorite-tag-highlighting-in-question-lists-be-changed?lq=1#comment901659_238591) - that is more than most feature requests can ever hope for. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I would know, 'cause I've made a few, all of which were pretty quietly ignored :) I didn't see that, and I'm very excited to no longer bleed my eyes onto my phone.

Comment: @cat well, even this does not guarantee anything, Nick said "we're working on it" on [some other request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131045/optimise-stack-exchange-user-flair-for-retina-displays#comment360851_131045) **four years ago**, just to vanish into thin air. Let's hope Jarrod is more serious/responsible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've updated the request per your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, much better now.

Answer (score 3):

Custom user style can this - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321085/4157407
Without icons in tags, but looks way better than original.

[image]

Comment: I've already got a userscript that applies the styling pictured above but thank you for including this here.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ At first I had same solution as in your proposal, but those rods felt a bit blatant, but my solution needs embedding an image which affects page loading time